# VSCode showing insufficient permision to save a file located in root/computer partition where my ubuntu is installed

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

VScode showing `Failed to save 'index.html': Insufficient permissions. Select 'Retry as Sudo' to retry as superuser`
while saving a file located in the root/computer directory how can I solve this?

I want autosave work without super user or keep super user active. How can I do this, please?

Comment: To avoid the need to use super user privileges to edit file/s you need to have write permissions, So it's more a system issue rather than vscode issue 

If you're trying to edit system files (or files that require sudo to edit) and can't use `Retry as sudo` working. I think there're many complaints about this already like https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/48659

Answer (score 0):

The issue in my access was that the auth popup had an issue, I noticed there's many apps with the same issue.

To resolve I'd suggest revising your sudo options and don't include `nopasswd`. In my case it happened that I upgraded to a newer OS version and both actions

The easiest way to make sure you've the same case is to go to `Settings > Users` You should see unlock option
[image: auth check]
Click it and in default you should get a popup requesting your password. If not that's your real issue it's not vscode